# Class C can have _______ 1s with the remaining bits 0s

Tags: computer-networks

> A subnet mask in class C can have _______ 1s with the remaining bits 0s.

MyApproach:

Class C subnet is 255.255.255.0.So, accordingly it has 9 1s on first byte,9 1s on second byte and 9 1s on third byte.etcSo total 27 1s but the Ans is 25

@Edit

For 255 it has 8 1s on first byte,8 1s on second and 8 1s  on third.=24 How 25?

> Can anyone guide What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you get 9 bits 1 in an octet (8 bits)?

Answer (score 1):

Check again your count of how many 1's are in the binary representation of 255.  Beyond that, there's nothing wrong with your reasoning.  The answer "25" is wrong.

Some examples are available in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork

Comment: I have edited my Ans

Comment: Not understood .I could not relate from the link .

Comment: @Jasonarora, It's not clear to me what you couldn't understand, so I wouldn't know how to begin to help. I believe I answered the question that was asked.   If you are having trouble understanding some aspect of the concepts of networking, I suspect you ask a new question focused on a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about.  As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the specific problem you happen to be working on.  (Caveat: This isn't the place to get someone to proof-read your homework answer.)

Comment: Homework? Is the learning problems becomes homework.Then,I will love homework.Thanx for your guidence